# swap image and toggle div onclick

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a dynamically populated unordered list. Every other list item is hidden. First list item contains an image, when clicked displays the list item immediately following. That part of my code is working fine. What I can't seem to figure out is how to swap the toggle image onclick. Right now the image stays the same

thank you for any help you can provide

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".slidingDiv").hide();

  $('.show_hide').click(function (e) {
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle("slow");
    var val = $(this).src() == "http://icdn.pro/images/en/m/i/minus-icone-9730-128.png" ? "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu/22/circle_add_plus-128.png" : "http://icdn.pro/images/en/m/i/minus-icone-9730-128.png";
    $(this).hide().src(val).fadeIn("slow");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="storeTable">
  <li id="one" class="alwaysVisable">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p class="descript">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu/22/circle_add_plus-128.png" class="show_hide" width="32" height="32">
  </li>
  <li class="slidingDiv">
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum.
  </li>
  <li id="two" class="alwaysVisable">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p class="descript">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu/22/circle_add_plus-128.png" class="show_hide" width="32" height="32">
  </li>
  <li class="slidingDiv">
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum.
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the jQuery `.attr()` method or Javascript's `src` property to `get` or `set` the `src` of an image. You also want to keep the context of the clicked image so that you can toggle to relevant element. For that you could replace:

```
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle("slow");
```

With:

```
$(this).closest('li').next().slideToggle('slow');
```

Or what I have used in the demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    //preload images
    $('<img/>',{src:"http://icdn.pro/images/en/m/i/minus-icone-9730-128.png"});
    $('<img/>',{src:"https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu/22/circle_add_plus-128.png"});
  
    $('.show_hide').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest("li").next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle("slow");
        var val = this.src == "http://icdn.pro/images/en/m/i/minus-icone-9730-128.png" ? "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu/22/circle_add_plus-128.png" : "http://icdn.pro/images/en/m/i/minus-icone-9730-128.png";
        $(this).hide().attr('src', val).fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="storeTable">
  <li id="one" class="alwaysVisable">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p class="descript">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu/22/circle_add_plus-128.png" class="show_hide" width="32" height="32">
  </li>
  <li class="slidingDiv">
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum.
  </li>
  <li id="two" class="alwaysVisable">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p class="descript">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu/22/circle_add_plus-128.png" class="show_hide" width="32" height="32">
  </li>
  <li class="slidingDiv">
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum.
  </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**

When not using absolute URLs, you want to use `.attr()` instead of `.src`. Change:

```
var val = this.src == "img/reward-info_on.png" ? "img/reward-info_off.png" : "img/reward-info_on.png";
```

To:

```
var val = $(this).attr('src') == "img/reward-info_on.png" ? "img/reward-info_off.png" : "img/reward-info_on.png";
```

Comment: So funny that you also chose to use both the `src` property and the `attr()` function, just like in ***my answer***.

Comment: I thought i had this working, but upon further testing, the image is not reverting back to the plus sign when i click the image a second time to "close" the div. i can see that it does on your snippet, but on my page it is staying on the minus. I have multiple other jquery scripts running on this page, could they be causing this code not to work? I appreciate any help you could provide

Comment: I would be happy to assist. How have you incorporated my answer into your code?

Comment: @Amit, from the SO code it is quite clear what the intention was; it would have been counterproductive to do it differently for difference sake.

Comment: i copied and pasted the code on to my page. updated the classes and urls and it seemed to be working fine. when i click the plus sign image, the images changes to a minus and the hidden div is made visable. then when i click the minus sign, the div goes back to hidden, but the minus sign stays a minus sign

Comment: My code or @Amit's code? Can you create a minimal demo that shows the current issue?

Comment: Would have been much better for you to post this as an **UPDATE** to your question. It's very difficult to read `code` in a comment. The issue is very simple. **The property, `this.src`, gives the absolute path -- so the comparison fails each time. Solution: use `$(this).attr('src')` instead of `this.src` in your `var val = .....` line.**

Comment: See my answer for how to update your question for easy readability.

Comment: sorry, couldnt see how to update my original question. Thank you so much. That was indeed the problem. You are amazing!

Comment: Pleasure was all mine. :-) Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

`src()` is not a method of the jQuery object. If you want to read / write the `src` attribure, you can either do it directly on the element (`this` inside the event handler), or using the jQuery `attr()` function. In the below code I used both: direct for reading, and `attr()` for writing:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".slidingDiv").hide();

  $('.show_hide').click(function (e) {
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle("slow");
    var val = this.src == "http://icdn.pro/images/en/m/i/minus-icone-9730-128.png" ? "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu/22/circle_add_plus-128.png" : "http://icdn.pro/images/en/m/i/minus-icone-9730-128.png";
    $(this).hide().attr('src', val).fadeIn("slow");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="storeTable">
  <li id="one" class="alwaysVisable">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p class="descript">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu/22/circle_add_plus-128.png" class="show_hide" width="32" height="32">
  </li>
  <li class="slidingDiv">
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum.
  </li>
  <li id="two" class="alwaysVisable">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p class="descript">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu/22/circle_add_plus-128.png" class="show_hide" width="32" height="32">
  </li>
  <li class="slidingDiv">
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum.
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You might also consider loading the images into an Image object so that the icons can be buffered in memory/cache.

Comment: @JustinPearce you can do so many other things as well, but that's outside the scope of the question if you ask me

Comment: I agree, simply an observation for those that might view the answer later. :D

Comment: I thought I was good, but upon testing further, it does not appear that the image is swapping back to the plus sign. i can see that it does on your snippet, but on my page it is staying on the minus when i "close" the expanded div. I have multiple other jquery scripts running on this page, could they be causing this code not to work?

Comment: I thought you liked @PeterKA 's version of my answer, why don't you ask him?

Comment: i didn't realize i could only like one. I tried both solutions, yours first, and seem to be having the same issue. I'll ask him. Thank you again for your help

Comment: I'd suggest you look for errors in the console. If something stops working, there's usually an exception thrown